# Need help understanding a step in a solution to solve a system of equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve the following equation:

$ax+by+cz = 0 ....(1)$

$x+y+z=0, .....(2)$

$bcx+cay+abz = (b-c) (c-a) (a - b) ......(3)$

I came across a solution that involves cross multiplication and substitution, and I am having trouble understanding a particular step. In the solution, the following equation is derived.

$k (bc (b-c)+ca (c-a)+ab (a - b)) )= (b-c) (c-a) (a - b).         ......(4)$

And then (5) is derived from (4) by simplification:

$k(-(b-c) (c-a) (a - b))) = (b-c) (c-a) (a - b)); ......(5)$

I am having trouble understanding how to factorize $bc (b-c)+ca (c-a)+ab (a - b))$ into $-(b-c) (c-a) (a - b)$. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

for reference here is the complete solution to the problem as given "solution: From (1) and (2), by cross multiplication,

$x/(b-c) = y/( c-a ) = z/(a-b)  =k$, suppose;

$x=k(b-c), y=k(c-a), z=k(a - b).$

Substituting in (3),

$k (bc (b-c)+ca (c-a)+ab (a - b)) )= (b-c) (c-a) (a - b).         (4)$

$k(-(b-c) (c-a) (a - b))) = (b-c) (c-a) (a - b); (5)$

hence

$k=-1; x=c-b,y=a-c, z=b-a.$ "

Comment: There's a typo in equation 2

Comment: @jjagmath sorry, i have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that all three factors in the final expression you're trying to get are in the original expression as well, but in separate terms. So we choose one of them, say $(a-b)$, leave the term with it alone and work on the other two, with the goal of trying to find the factor $(a-b)$ in their sum:

$$\begin{align}
bc(b-c) + ca(c-a) + ab(a-b) &= b^2c - bc^2 + ac^2 - a^2c + ab(a-b) \\[2px]
&= b^2c - a^2c + ac^2 - bc^2 + ab(a-b) \\[2px]
&= c(b-a)(b+a) + c^2(a-b) + ab(a-b) \\[2px]
&= -c(a-b)(a+b) + c^2(a-b) +ab(a-b) \\[2px]
&= (a-b) \left[\, -c(a+b) + c^2 + ab \,\right] \\[2px]
&= (a-b) \left[ c^2 - ca - cb + ab \right] \\[2px]
&= (a-b)(c-a)(c-b) \\[2px]
&= -(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) 
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you so much. really grateful.